# Insert with auto increment

Tags: sql-server

i have this request:

```
INSERT INTO E_COURR (ID_COURR, ID_TYPECOURRIEL, LL_COU_SUJET, TXT_COU_CONTENU)
VALUES (isnull((select max(isnull(ID_COURR,0))+1 from E_COURR WITH (HOLDLOCK, UPDLOCK);), 1, 'some text....', 'some text....');
GO
```

I have this Error Message:

```
Msg 1046, Level 15 , State 1, Line 23
Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed .
Msg 319, Level 15 , State 1, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near the keyword ' with '. If the statement is a common table expression or XMLNAMESPACES clause, the previous statement must end with a semicolon.
```

Comment: who put a negative vote , can give you the reason so I can improve my post . Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have ID_COURR declared as an IDENTITY column that way the auto increment would take care of itself

If that's impossible then you could just get the identity into a variable first

```
DECLARE @E_COURR bigint-- Or whatever Type it is
SET @E_COURR = (select max(isnull(ID_COURR,0))+1 from E_COURR;)
```

And then use that Value

```
INSERT INTO E_COURR (ID_COURR, ID_TYPECOURRIEL, LL_COU_SUJET, TXT_COU_CONTENU)
VALUES ( @E_COURR, 1, 'some text....', 'some text....');
```

But as I say you should almost certainly be recreating the table with an IDENTITY column

Bon chance!

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out before using `IDENTITY` will solve this automatically

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, SomeValue INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl(SomeValue) VALUES(100),(200),(300);

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

But, just to offer another chance in case you cannot go this way, you could place your sub-select within a `SELECT` instead of `VALUES`:

```
DECLARE @tbl2 TABLE(ID INT NOT NULL, SomeValue INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl2(ID,SomeValue) 
SELECT isnull((select max(ID) FROM @tbl2),0)+1,100;
INSERT INTO @tbl2(ID,SomeValue) 
SELECT isnull((select max(ID) FROM @tbl2),0)+1,200;
INSERT INTO @tbl2(ID,SomeValue) 
SELECT isnull((select max(ID) FROM @tbl2),0)+1,300;

SELECT * FROM @tbl2;
```